# Should old unanswered questions that need a photo for proper answers be closed?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that many of our unanswered questions are practically unanswerable without a photo, or in some cases, a lot more detail. I would vote to close many of these, but I would like to know what everyone else thinks.

- Should I wait for a certain length of inactivity?
- Should I just vote to close these whenever it seems the original poster isn't coming back?
- Should I just leave them?

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/q/451/26.

Comment: I've also seen wax eagles answer to [this](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/448/new-close-reasons-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-and-custom-sub-reasons-off) question.

Comment: @NiallC. Thanks for the link. The question is similar. Basically, I'm asking whether it would be well received for me to go through and vote to close these, or if I would just be a pain. These questions annoy my, because they are clearly unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should close them.  For the most part if the question is older than a few weeks it has been abandoned by the user and the chances of them returning to provide more details is slim.