# Should I add updates throughout time to an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Let's say I post a question after doing some research, taking pictures, etc, and it has no answer. My problem was in a state, f.g, **state A**. As time passes, the plant or whatever in question, might be in **state B** and after some time in **state C**, and so on. Then I think: *oh, if I edit my question and show the current state (B now), it might add richness to the question for someone in the future to answer.*

I read this question [Should old unanswered questions that need a photo for proper answers be closed?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/should-old-unanswered-questions-that-need-a-photo-for-proper-answers-be-closed) , not focusing on the closing thing, but the photos. I thought: then this situation is the opposite! Adding updates to an unanswered question makes it more prone to be answered in the future, as every time is more complete!

In my case, I asked [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63601/is-my-avocado-tree-dying-due-to-transplant-shock), and my plant is in another state (most leaves fell and the plant is drooping). I took some pictures and I thought it would be a good idea to add at the end of my question:

> Update 1! One week later, my plant is X, Y, Z, picture_n

And keep adding **MAJOR-updates-only** until it recovers or dies (I guess), and only major so as to not have an extremely long question. So these updates should take months. **For me, it can be nice for future answerers or people having a similar problem doing their research, so they can see a future state and try to take action**. It seems more scientific and helpful to me, and it can prevent future questions that are the same. But I am not sure if it's a good idea because it's true the question might end up very verbose and long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are more than welcome to add useful details to your questions. Often enough askers are actively prompted to add some specific details, but the kind of update you suggested is also helpful. If you use a bit of common sense, it should be reasonably easy to be concise enough while giving lots of relevant details. So feel free to edit your posts as you see fit.

The other post you linked to is about questions that are unanswerable as is, which is a clear reason to close them. On many of the larger SE sites with more traffic, they would probably be closed rather quickly with the option to reopen after a suitable edit. Knowing that this can be a steep learning curve especially for new users, many smaller sites tend to ask for clarity first and then close if the post seems abandoned. Both approaches are within the rules of the SE network.